# Why is $K^{\mathrm{sep}}$ dense in $K_v^{\mathrm{sep}}$?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, complete-spaces, local-field, separable-extension

Let $K$ be a global field and $v$ be a non-archimedean place of $K$. Given a field $k$, let $k^{\mathrm{sep}}$ be a separable closure inside an algebraic closure $\overline k$.

> I would like to know why $K^{\mathrm{sep}}$ dense in $K_v^{\mathrm{sep}}$.

I think that $\overline K$ is dense in $\overline{K_v}$ as shown on [p. 33 of Non-Archimedean Operator Theory](https://books.google.at/books?id=SMztCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false), so it would settle the case where $K$ is perfect.

I've heard that Krasner's lemma can help, but I don't see how. Thanks.

Comment: are you aware that if $\beta\in K^\mathrm{sep}$ then $K(\beta)$ is dense in $K_v(\beta)$?

Comment: @AlexMathers : I am not sure. Does this rely on Krasner's lemma? And how to conclude about my question?

Comment: (See also Corollary 2.7 in the file Galois groups of local and global fields (https://alex-youcis.github.io/localglobalgalois.pdf) for the case of algebraic closure.)

Answer (score 2):

Prove the following as an exercise (no Krasner's lemma needed):

> If $\beta\in \overline K$ then $K(\beta)$ is dense in $K_v(\beta)$.

Now here is an outline on how to proceed:

Let $\alpha\in K_v^\mathrm{sep}$, let $\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n$ be the conjugates of $\alpha$ and let $f\in K_v[x]$ be the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K_v$. Choose $g\in K[x]$ to be an approximation of $f$ so that each coefficient of $g-f$ has absolute value smaller than $\min_{i=2,\dots,n}|\alpha-\alpha_i|/|\alpha|^n$. Conclude that $|g(\alpha)|<\min_{i=2,\dots,n}|\alpha-\alpha_i|$. By writing $g$ as a product of linear polynomials deduce that $g$ has a root $\beta$ for which $|\alpha-\beta|<\min_{i=2,\dots,n}|\alpha-\alpha_i|$, and use Krasner's lemma to deduce that $\alpha\in K_v(\beta)$, which means by the lemma above you can approximate $\alpha$ by elements of $K(\beta)$ and hence by elements of $K^\mathrm{sep}$.